# IntelliJ TypeScript import of Angular marked with squiggle

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4 to develop Angular (4 not js) app. Everything works and running fine but IntelliJ marks all `@angular` imports in TypeScript files with a red squiggle.

The error message is `TS2307: Cannot find module '@nagular/abc'`

There is also issue open in Jetbrain's support [Typescript does not resolve modules through tsconfig.json's baseUrl](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205979284-Typescript-does-not-resolve-modules-through-tsconfig-json-s-baseUrl-)

[image]

This is my tsconfig.json file.

Please note that tsconfig.json file is stored not in the root of the project but in ./app/ui directory - if that matters.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   "alwaysStrict": true,
   "noImplicitReturns": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "module": "system",
   "target": "es5",
   "removeComments": true,
   "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
   "outDir": "generated",
   "inlineSourceMap": true,
   "importHelpers": true,
   "baseUrl": ".",
   "paths": {
     "tslib": [
      "../../node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"
     ]
   },
   "skipLibCheck": true,
   "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
   "lib"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It could be that Intellij is expecting a code style defined in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: what does it say when you hover over the red lines of the imports?

Comment: I've add the error message

Comment: Is `node_modules` directory excluded?

Comment: @MuliYulzary yes, it seems that IntelliJ force node_modules to be excluded

Comment: it's only partially excluded by default - packages listed in package.json are still indexed for completion; and excluding doesn't affect Typescript compiler service anyway. Please share your tsconfig.json

Comment: Did you try removing `baseUrl` or adding `rootDirs`?

Comment: It looks like changing `"module": "system"` to `"module": "commonjs"` fixes the problem but I need to do more testing to make sure this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

All of your angular related package should be in.
for e.g:

```
node_modules/@angular/common/index.d.ts
node_modules/@angular/compiler/index.d.ts
node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts
node_modules/@angular/http/index.d.ts
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index.d.ts
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.d.ts
node_modules/@angular/router/index.d.ts
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/index.d.ts
```

However, All of these should be there if you have used the package.json file from the standard quickstart https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html and run `npm install`

Also check `tsconfig.json` settings of your IDE

```
File->settings->Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript ->enable typescript compiler & Use tsconfig.json
```

Comment: I don't see any index.d.ts in those paths

Comment: Also I don't have `Enabled TypeScript Compiler` because I don't want IntelliJ to compile the .ts files

Answer (score 0):

When using `"module": "system"` TypeScript uses Classic module resolution, which does not resolve node modules, see details at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

To make it work, you need to switch to a different module system, like CommonJS, or there might be another configuration to explicitly include node_modules in resolution while using `"module": "system"`.